# Do file systems affect the available storage space?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, btrfs, storage

I have heard some group discussing file systems (btrfs vs ext4 and something like that) to use in Linux on computers with less disk space (like 32GB ideapad, notebook etc.).

Does the filesystem choice really affect the used by the same file? I mean can we have more available disk space by choosing a different file system?  for exactly same result.

Comment: What is "exactly" the same result? Do checksums matter? CoW? Snapshots?

Comment: Can I please check... for a very small storage area (i.e. your 32GB), you want to maximise the effective space available for file storage. So you're looking for a Linux-appropriate filesystem with the lowest space overhead. Is that right?

Comment: Are you storing a hand-full of files or many millions of files?

Comment: Actually I have a notepad and running debian. Usally i install numerous application. So i always left with 2GB free space. Does again installing debain with different filesystem (ext4, ext3, fat32 or any other) will give me more free space for exact apps and file i used to have

Comment: Few years ago I installed headless Debian and few tools I needed in 512 MB. All thanks to btrfs compression.

Comment: Do you mean btrfs does the Job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can make a lot of difference...  Usually it makes the most difference on file systems with a lot of smaller files.  So it may not make a difference to your video collection (mostly GB files) or even you music collection (mostly MB files).  But a file system filled with many files only a few KB will definitely see a difference.

---

There are some difference on the meta data required per file.  Here meta data means everything that's not contained in the file data such as the file's name, its permissions, timestamps, and custom file system properties.

It really depends on the features of the file system and sometimes the way it's configured, but this data can be bytes to kilobytes per file irrespective of file size.

---

Files are not stored as individual bytes but blocks of bytes.  On ext4 a block is by default 4 KiB for filesystems over 512MB.  So a file that's exactly 4096 bytes will take up exactly 4096 bytes on disk, but so will a file that's 4095 bytes or even just 1 byte.  A file that's 4097 bytes will again take up 8192.  This is known as padding.

It is possible to format some many file systems with custom (smaller) block sizes.  This can reduce the padding but there can also be side effects.  Some modern hard drives perform badly with smaller blocks.  Theoretically it could actually reduce capacity as more space needs to be used to mark which blocks are allocated, though I've never seen this happen myself.

Now not all file systems will wast the block in padding.  Some filesystems, including btrfs, will allocated more than one file to a block.  See [block suballocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_suballocation).

---

Then there's a more obvious feature.  Some file systems can transparently compress the contents of files.  There's no guarantee that this will successfully compress file contents but it can be very successful.

An example file system here is zfs. See [enabling compression in zfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_suballocation).

Comment: What may be the noticeable difference for end user.

Comment: That's impossible to say without seeing the exact file system and even then it would be a matter of "try it and see".  The data lost through padding blocks could add up to several GB or it might be only a few MB.

Comment: `btrfs` also has transparent compression.  For typical files, this can save a lot of space.  However, if your data/files are already compressed, trying to compress it again won't help  much and may even hurt.